# Javascript Script Engine

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm trying to get this script engine to work but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`. I look at the line where it is thrown (my return line toward the very end of my code), but I can't seem to solve my problem. Do anyone have experience with javascript engines that could help?

```
package com.example.lab2;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

/**
 * @author jamiekujawa
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * A string builder to represent the first number entered in the series     of entries
     */
    private String expression1;

    /**
     * A string builder to represent the second number entered in the series of entries
     *
    private StringBuilder expression2;*/

    /**
     * A string to represent the last operator performed
     *
    private String oldOperator;*/

    private String foo = "";


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // declare all buttons used within the layout
        Button zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button times = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontimes);
        Button clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
        Button equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEqual);
        Button decimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDecimal);
        Button divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondivide);
        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplus);
        Button subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonminus);

        // declare main text view
        final TextView main = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CalculatorText);

        // Main Strings to represent the expressions
        expression1 = new String();
        //expression2 = new StringBuilder();
        main.setText(expression1.concat("0.0"));

        /*
         * Set up all key listener events
         */
        zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("0");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("0");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }
        });

        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("1");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("1");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }

        });

        two.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("2");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("2");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }

        });

        three.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("3");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("3");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }

        });

        four.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("4");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("4");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }

        });

        five.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("5");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("5");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }

        });

        six.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("6");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("6");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }

        });

        seven.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("7");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("7");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }

        });

        eight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("8");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("8");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }

        });

        nine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(expression1.toString().equals("0.0")) {
                    expression1 = new String("9");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }else {
                    expression1.concat("9");
                    main.setText(expression1);
                }
            }

        });

        times.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                expression1.concat("*");
                main.setText(expression1);
            }

        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                main.setText("0.0");
                expression1 = new String("0.0");
                //expression2 = new StringBuilder();
            }

        });

        equal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(foo);
                if(expression1.equals("")){
                    main.setText("0.0");
                }else {
                    try {
                        main.setText(evaluate(expression1));
                    } catch (ScriptException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        decimal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                expression1.concat(".");
                main.setText(expression1);
            }

        });

        divide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                expression1.concat("/");
                main.setText(expression1);
            }

        });

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                expression1.concat("+");
                main.setText(expression1);
            }

        });

        subtract.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                expression1.concat("-");
                main.setText(expression1);
            }

        });
    }

    /**
     * This method will evaluate an operation using expression1 and javaScriptEngineManager
     *
     * @param buttonPressed or operation to be performed
     * @return the result of the operation
     */
    public String evaluate(String buttonPressed) throws ScriptException{
        //System.out.println(foo);
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        foo = engine.eval(expression1).toString();
        return foo;
    }

}
```

Comment: It might be beneficial to show us the error output from your code.

Comment: include the stackTrace or it will be very hard to help you

Comment: okay I guess there is no error message now, but when I type in numbers or the operators the main screen just goes blank until I hit enter. Which then it just goes back to zero.